# Widget dont show in the menu in android 4+ even after restart

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've added a widget to my application.

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.WidgetProvider" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>
```

It appears in the menu in the emulator with android 2.3.

But it doesnt appear on my devices and in the emulator with android 4+ even after restart.
I have an activity with

```
<activity android:name=".new_UI.SplashActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

That is launched before I try to find the widget in the menu.

How to make it appear?

Comment: You should see the widget in the menu, since Honeycomb appwidgets could not appear because they are in stopped state by default, but you do have an activity that takes the app out of this state. Perhaps something in your AndroidManifest.xml? Can you post the whole manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Is this application installed to the SD card on your emulator?

Try setting [installLocation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) to internalOnly.